# Is "Harley machine" really a phrase used for a Harley-Davidson motorcycle?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrases

In the musical movie "Little Shop of Horrors" (1986), in the song "Feed Me (Git It)", the lyrics go:

> Seymour: [Sung] Gee I'd like a ***Harley machine***
>
> Toolin' around like I was James Dean
>
> Makin' all the guys on the corner turn green

Obviously whoever wrote the lyrics had to rhyme with "Dean" and "green", so "machine" fits, but is that *actually* what anyone would call a motorbike? "Harley machine"? Or maybe it's specifically intended to sound stupid/silly since "Seymour" is a very meak and "nerdy" character -- the opposite of who you'd imagine driving a motorcycle?

Comment: I doubt that there are many men over 40 who would not associate "Harley machine" with the motorcycle.  Certainly "a Harley" is idiomatic, and adding "machine" is not all that odd.

Comment: And I'll note that my grandparents referred to their car as "the machine".  This was perfectly idiomatic in the day.

Comment: And also note that *Little Shop of Horrors* was odd in many ways.

Comment: There is no reason why the meek and nerdy Seymour would not *like* to have a Harley machine, perhaps just a fantasy he is singing about – wanting to be like James Dean and making guys' heads turn.

Comment: In the 1970s a British motorcycle magazine used to refer to the Vincent Black Knight as a 'gentleman's express carriage'.

Answer (score 2):

***[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/machine)*** defines as “old“ the use of the term machine for the following items:

1)an automobile or airplane.

2)a typewriter.

3) a bicycle or ***motorcycle.***

From : [Harley-Davidson: The Good, the Bad, and the Legendary](https://books.google.it/books?id=er1WUzVjDD4C&pg=PA66&lpg=PA66&dq=harley%20machine&source=bl&ots=7bL6OfwiMc&sig=ACfU3U2xN_ICsjHfjgqanz0_1Zf2vV51KQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjtioTm7KzpAhUN8xQKHQePDtgQ6AEwE3oECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=harley%20machine&f=false)
by Voyageur Press

> The first Harley was sold before it was finished to a local man named Meyer, who put 6,000 miles (9,654 km) on the machine before selling it to a George Lyon, who added 15,000 miles (24,135 km).

[Motorcycle:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorcycle)

> Dual purpose machines like the dual-sport style are made to go off-road but include features to make them legal and comfortable on the street as well

(Wikipedia)

So, the expression “Harley machine” though dated, is correct.